# javascript onload page radio checked

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a function that enables or disables form elements based on which radio item is checked.  It is working ok.  However, I wish that one of the radio buttons to be checked at page load with the appropriate form elements already disabled or enabled.

Right now on page load, I have one of the radio buttons checked on the form itself but the javascript will fire when there is a change.

Here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function customerChoice() {
            if (document.getElementById('radio1').checked) {
                document.getElementById('company').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('onetime').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('span1').style.color = '#cccccc';
                document.getElementById('span2').style.color = '#000000';
                }
            if (document.getElementById('radio2').checked) {
                document.getElementById('company').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('onetime').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('span1').style.color = '#000000';
                document.getElementById('span2').style.color = '#cccccc';
            }
        }
window.onload = customerChoice();

</script>
```

And here are the two radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="type" id="radio1" value="C" onclick="customerChoice()" checked />Current Customer<br />

<input type="radio" name="type" id="radio2" value="O" onclick="customerChoice()" />One Time Customer<br />
```

Need help figuring out what to change in order to make the javascript fire upon loading.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
window.onload = customerChoice;
```

The way you have it runs the function immediately, and sets the `onload` handler to the result (which is `undefined`, since the function doesn't return anything), rather than to the function itself. It's not working because it runs before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Was just about to add the same answer myself...The parentheses at the end cause the function to be run immediately, rather than when the page finishes loading.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the `customerChoice()` function inside an anonymous function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  customerChoice();  
};
```